# How to display controller error messages in your Rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I am adding some tests (following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html) and would like to add some feedback on my controller tests to show why my tests fail because I am missing some validation etc.

Take this simple example:

```
test "should create article" do
  assert_difference('Article.count') do
    post articles_url, params: { article: { body: 'Rails is awesome!', title: 'Hello Rails' } }
  end
  assert_redirected_to article_path(Article.last)
end
```

Lets say my `Article` model has a validation where `user_id` is required.  This test just fails.  I found another post on here with the following suggestion:

```
assert_equal([], assigns(:article).errors.full_messages)
```

I must be missing something or my inexperience with testing syntax etc. may be the issue because I can't get this to work - the `assigns(:article).errors.full_messages` is always `[]` even when the validation fails.  I am fine with the added assertion but I was also thinking to just add the error messages to the optional test failure message.

Comment: In your controller do you have @article instance variable which could be something like `@article = Article.create(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test "should create article" do
  assert_difference('Article.count') do
    post articles_url, params: { article: { body: 'Rails is awesome!', title: 'Hello Rails' } }
    puts assigns(:article).errors.full_message
  end
  assert_redirected_to article_path(Article.last)
end
```

The trick was adding the display of the error in the do block :)

Comment: assigns has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it, add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile. ;-)